# How to send the file to node.js and back end when using ng-flow to take the file

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, mongodb

I am using angularJS's ng-flow to upload a img in my app. the prob is that I successfully upload the file flow and I am not able to send the file to node.js and save it to mongoDb.

Code (FrontEnd)(HTML):

```
 <div class="circle-photo-container" flow-init="saveImage($flow)" flow-files-submitted="saveImage($flow)"   flow-file-success="saveImage($flow)" flow-attrs="{accept:'image/*'}">
                <div class="photo-container" >
                    <div ng-hide="$flow.files.length" class="circle-photo">
                        <div class="content">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <img ng-show="$flow.files.length" flow-img="$flow.files[0]" width="100" height="100" style="margin-left: 37%">
                </div>
                <div class="photo-upload-container" flow-btn>
                    <i ng-hide="$flow.files.length" class="fa fa-2x fa-camera upload-button"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.saveImage = function(flow){
console.log('hello')
            if(flow){
            var abc = !!{png:1,gif:1,jpg:1,jpeg:1}[flow.files[0].getExtension()]
            if(abc == true){
                $scope.groupData.picURL = flow.files[0];
                $scope.img = flow.files.length;
            }else{
                flow.cancel()
            }
            }
        }
```

I have file object in flow.files[0] and $scope.groupData.picURL.
Now can I make a POST request to the server and then save it to mongoDB.
Please help with the example Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your not actually reading the file at all, you're just retrieving the file object. You will need to use the `FileReader` object to read the data, so that it can be passed to the server. I've set up a function which returns the `FileReader` object which will get the resulting data from the image. You can call that function from within your existing save function.

```
var getFileReader = function( $scope ) {

    var fileReader = new FileReader();

    fileReader.onloadend = function() {

        $scope.img = fileReader.result;

    }

    return fileReader;
};
```

And then within your function call:

```
$scope.saveImage = function(flow){

        if(flow){
            var abc = !!{png:1,gif:1,jpg:1,jpeg:1}[flow.files[0].getExtension()]

            if(abc == true){
                var fileReader = getFileReader( $scope ),
                    file = flow.files[0];

                 fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);

                 $scope.$apply();

            }else{
                flow.cancel()
            }
      }

 }
```

Comment: getting this err  TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': The argument is not a Blob

Comment: That means the `flow.files[0]` object is not a readable image file, which means you're not selecting the correct file.  See for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader.readAsDataURL  Can you set up a jsfiddle?

Comment: I have solved that issue by passing flow.files[0].file instead of flow.files[0].

Comment: Is it possible to get on server side as req.file. If so which object is passed along with http post request?